# How to have an alternate function signature in C++, due to unused parameter in a bool typed template function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, signature, compile-time

Disclaimer: this post is question, not a problem to solve with workarounds from what I am proposing.

I aim to have a library providing several instances of my function `increment`, based on a unique definition to avoid code redundancy:

```
template <bool modify>
int increment(int a, int b) {
    if constexpr(modify)
        return a+=b;
    else
        return ++a;
}
```

When correctly instanciated, I have two different implementations depending of the value of `modify`.

The thing is that when `modify` is false, the function parameter `b` is still mandatory while never used.

My question: Since it is theorically deducible in this example, is it possible to ask to the compiler to provide an instanciation with the signature:

`template int increment<false>(int a)` without implementing it myself (in which case the function `increment`can keep having a single implementation).

And so in in my lib's `.h` I could have something like:

```
template <bool modify>
int increment(int a, int b);

int increment(int a); //Which would be linked to the instance: template int increment<false>(int a)
```

This is a simplified problem that, I hope, illustrates well my question.
I don't know if C++ standard provides such a solution, or if I should go near metaprogramming extensions, or go to a specific compiler.

I know that assigning a default value for `b` could be a workaround, but this would be solving this particular example, while I am seeking for an answer to the previously asked question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `std::optional` ? There is no way to let the compiler automagically generate a different overload

Comment: you could also rename `increment` to `increment_implementation` and then provide two different overloads of `increment` that both call `increment_implementation`

Comment: This is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are many ways to achieve the same effect, just not in the way you wish

Comment: the question is unclear. You already have two seperate implementations in the two branches of the if. Rather than using `constexpr if` you can use two separate overloads. I understand that this is a simplified example, but your example does not illustrate the actual issue you are trying to solve

Comment: "my function increment must have a single implementation" -- could you explain why? From the perspective of the caller it should generally not matter if you have a template or two overloads. I second this smells like xy-problem.

Comment: your `increment` is basically just `if constexpr(modify) return implementation_a(a,b); else return implementation_b(a);` and there is no more or less "redundancy" or repeated code if you let the caller directly call either `implementation_a` or `implementation_b`

Comment: You could use a default value for the second argument, use overloads or other options..

Comment: It seems my question was unclear and yes it can appear an XY problem. My question was about: is it possible or not to let the compiler automatically generate the overload `template int increment<false>(int a)`, and based on you answers it seems to be no, which was the information I was seeking. Sorry for the misleading fact that I was having a problem to solve, while I wanted an answer to a question.

Comment: @roli Doesn't the answers you've gotten answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function template with a single implementation:

```cpp
template <bool modify, class... Args>
int increment(Args... args) {
    return modder<modify>(args...).res;
}
```

`modder` on the other hand is a class that has a specialization since function templates can't be specialized to have different parameter lists, but class templates can:

```cpp
template <bool>
struct modder {        // the primary template will match the `true` case
    modder(int a, int b) : res(a + b) {}
    int res;
};

template <>
struct modder<false> { // specialization for the `false` case
    modder(int a) : res(a + 1) {}
    int res;
}
```

---

Inspired by [Red.Wave's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355012/7582247), here's another version that requires 1 argument if `modify` is `false` and 2 arguments if `modify` is `true`:

```cpp
template <bool modify, class... Args>
    requires(sizeof...(Args) == modify + 1)
int increment(Args... args) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1) {
        // just return the single argument + 1
        return (..., (args + 1));
    } else {
        // return the sum of the two arguments
        return (... + args);
    }
}
```

Comment: To explain the rationale for your first solution -- function templates can't be specialized to have different parameter lists, but class templates can be specialized to have completely different member functions of the same name

Comment: @M.M I added that to the answer to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I like it, but the voodoo level is a bit high. Less dependence on library is a plus, OTH. I am just wondering why would the function need 2 markers for number of arguments( the `bool` flag + parameters)?

Comment: @Red.Wave  _"voodoo level"_ - :-) I was contemplating `return (..., ++args);` for the one argument version. Not sure if that would help - _"why would the function need 2 markers"_ - I'm not sure from where the `modify` template parameter originates (it could come from some levels above) and since `false` should make `increment` take exactly one argument and `true` should make it take exactly two arguments, that's what I went for.

Comment: I am a wizard too. I can read your spell, but I guess it dazzles some.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to challenge your design. I just remove the explicit template parameter:

```
auto next(auto x auto ...y)
requires (sizeof...(y)<2)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(y))
       return x + get<0>(std::tie(y...));
    else
       return x + 1;
};

auto x=next(7,8);
auto y=next(x);
```

I can achieve similar results for this special case with default argument value as well:

```
int next(int a, int b=1){ return a+b; };
```

But I guess that'd be an oversimplification of a more complicated problem you didn't want to share.